# Issue with ant-design ( NG-Zorro) carousel swiping

Tags: angular, swipe, antd, hammer.js, ng-zorro-antd

I have the issue with ant-design ( NG-Zorro) carousel swiping.

Swipe by mouse does not work.

How can I fix it?

https://ng.ant.design/components/carousel/en

[image]

Comment: Can you check that you've imported hammer.js into your angular app? `import 'hammerjs';`

Comment: Where should I import it?

Comment: Check below please, let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have not installed `hammer.js`, first

```
npm install --save hammerjs
```

You can import into your `main.ts` or `polyfills.ts` by adding

```
import 'hammerjs';
```

Alternatively you can in your `index.html`:

```
<head>
  <!-- ... -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/hammer.js/2.0.8/hammer.min.js"></script>
  <!-- ... -->
</head>
```

Or in your `angular.json` add it to the `scripts` array

```
{
    // ...
    "scripts": [
      "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/hammer.js/2.0.8/hammer.min.js"
    ]
    // ...
}
```

Hope it helps.